# Scrapy to extract data from javascript script

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to extract the odds of games from an espn website. The 'moneyLine' odds are buried in a script that I just can't figure out how to access. Ideally I would have the odds in rows for each game. I've managed to extract team names and scores in rows, I would like odds to go with it.

```
scrapy shell
fetch('http://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1')
response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'moneyLine')]/text()")
```

This is the output

```
[<Selector xpath="//script[contains(., 'moneyLine')]/text()" data='\n\t\t\tvar espn = espn || {};\n\n\t\t\t// Build '>]
```

Here is a sample from firefox inspector window, I can see the 'moneyLine' items, just can't isolate them
[image]

Comment: it can gives you all script as one string and you have to use standard string functions or regex to work with this. If you get string which is correct JSON string then you can use module `json` to convert it into python dictionary.

Comment: page can use javascript to read data from another url (mostly as JSON data). If you find this url using DevTool in Firefox then you can read it with scrapy.

Comment: is 'page' a method? What 'another url' are you referring to?

Comment: `page` means `web page` / `portal` - You have to use `DevTool` to check all `XHR` requests - if one of them sends back your data then you have `another url`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is in `<script>` between `data:` and `queue:` in JSON format.

You can use standard string functions (ie. `find()`, slicing) to cut off this part.
And then you can use module `json` to convert to python dictionary.
And then you have to only find where `moneyLine` is in this dictionary.

```
scrapy shell 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1'

# get `<script>` as text
items = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'moneyLine')]/text()")
txt = items.extract_first()

# find start and end of data 
#(I found this manually checking txt)
start = txt.find('data:') + 6 # manually found how many add to get correct JSON string
end = txt.find('queue:') - 6  # manually found how many substract to get correct JSON string

json_string = txt[start:end]

# convert to python dictionary
import json
data = json.loads(json_string)

# example data 
#(I found this manually using `data.keys(), data['sports'][0].keys(), etc.)
data['sports'][0]['leagues'][0]['events'][0]['odds']['home']['moneyLine']
```

Comment: Thank you! This get's me most of the way there. Clearly, I have some learning to do with xpath and json...just need to find the time